# How can I decrypt the credit card numbers I get from the api?

Tags: api, magento-1.9

I am trying to decrypt the cc numbers after receiving them from the soap API. How can I do this vb?

I am using the following chunk of code to get the encrypted cc num

```
Dim ccNum = test.getSalesOrder.payment.cc_number_enc
```

Can I add a decrypt option in the API? If so how?

**Edit**

Thanks everyone for commenting and answering. This has been a good information and think it will help others.

To answer some questions.

We are using our own processing system.

We have a system in place for storing credit card numbers that is PCI Compliment. The problem is getting that information to that system.

**Edit**

Anybody reading this post it is important to read all the comments. Decrypting/storing credit cards is not a good idea, unless you can justify your security.

Comment: where are they coming from? What encryption scheme did they use? More specifics please.

Comment: What do you mean where are they coming from? I am using the soap version 2 API. I use the following cc_number_enc on a salesOrderPaymentEntity object. It is magento's default encryption scheme.

Comment: This is not really what you are looking for, but this page has some code for doing it in code, rather than SOAP. http://www.opencart60s.com/magento/how-do-i-decrypt-the-credit-card-number-provided-through-the-webservice-api-16739.html (look for user_17336)

Comment: I already viewed that source. Not what I need or what to do. Thanks though.

Comment: You shouldn't ever do this, ever.

Comment: Why not? It doesn't seem reasonable to me to have to check every order on the backend for the cc number.

Comment: @philwinkle Credit card numbers appear on the backend as is. Only thing protecting them is a username and password. That is the same thing that protects the API. I don't understand how this is something you shouldn't do.

Comment: Credit card numbers should not be stored, period. If you're using the builtin CC Saved method you should move away from it quickly. If your store is ever compromised the attacker has both the CC numbers *and* the encryption key right there for them to decrypt. This is not in the best interest of your customers and I personally would never shop at a store where this was the practice.

Comment: PCI compliance violations cost at least $5,000 - 100,000 a month. Source:  http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/ What is the store URL and who is your processor?

Comment: The time is coming soon where people who don't understand why this shouldn't be done will be former business owners when caught storing this data in a non-secure manner. And a name and a password is considered to be a non-secure manner. Pretty much what my credit card processor told me today when certain things came under discussion.

Comment: @philwinkle thanks for the feed back, but I don't believe that. Companies like amazon store you credit card information. As look as I do in a secure manner I don't see why I can't do the same.

Comment: @ka8609 the company I am working for has there own processor. That is why I need a way to decrypt these numbers. I will have a window service pull orders from magneto, create an order in our other system and update the status of the order. I need the cc numbers for this. That is why I am using the API.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I don't see the owners of amazon becoming former business owners in the future at all. I am not storing the information in an insecure manner. I understand a username and password is insecure... that is why I brought it up.

Comment: The credit card numbers should not even be stored in Magento in the first place. That is the issue. The "Saved Credit Card Number" was from 2008 when Magento first started and should only be used for demo sites. If you wanted to make this "PCI Compliant", the CC numbers would never be stored in Magento, but you run a service during order creation to your processor that sends them the CC number and sends back a token (with the token you can do captures, voids, etc). After the order has been created is too late and not PCI Compliant. I'm telling you this from experience of making CC extensions.

Comment: So is amazon not PCI compliant? I know for a fact they store cc numbers. I am interested in this extensions on capture credit card numbers. Do you have an example?

Comment: Amazon stores tokens and the last 4 digits of the credit card on it's site. The credit card is stored with the processor. Did your processor give you a technical book about tokens? It should be pretty standard in 2014. Are you allowed to say your processor? I'm not trying to mean or anything like that, but the liability and risk is monstrous not just for the company but also for the developer. I'll check to see if I can point you in the right direction with an example. May take a day or two.

Comment: You also have to remember Amazon spends around over $100 million a year on security/infrastructure to ensure they are PCI Compliant and doing everything correctly. I don't think anyone running on Magento has that kind of budget.

Comment: Amazon is PCI compliant because they don't do what you think they do. As functionally described by other commenters... so no further need to elaborate. As to the company having their own processor, then the processor needs to provide a gateway module for Magento so you can stop storing credit card numbers that you have to decode to submit. Something along the lines of how Authorize.net's CIM system works, or a gateway module along the lines of how USA ePay works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at:

[Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/5345da52778cc6f5f31938ffd21fccfdd353435c/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cc.php)

[Mage_Core_Model_Encryption](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/5345da52778cc6f5f31938ffd21fccfdd353435c/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php)

The encryption key is stored on disk at `app/etc/local.xml`.

How you implement decryption in your own application is outside the scope of Magento. Adding a decrypt option to the API sounds like a questionable idea. If you have to ask, the answer is probably "you can't". If, instead, you already knew that you wanted to add this to the API and your company's controller says "yes we are allowed do this", then it seems unlikely that you would need to ask this question here.

Comment: does anyone have an idea of why this data is even in the API? What good is encrypted credit card data if there is no way included to decrypt it?

Comment: @pspahn Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into that. I don't believe this out of the scope of magento. I am confident you can add it, I just don't have the skill to do so.

Comment: I  meant the decryption of something in your VB application is outside the scope of Magento. I am confident you can add this to the API as well, but as @philwinkle said, you probably shouldn't be doing this. On the off chance that your business *is* fully aware of the PCI standards they will need to comply with (or potentially face a crippling audit) to have this sort of feature, my answer should point you in the right direction.